# Animating a drawer using jQuery in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-animate

I have a drawer hidden behind a panel using absolute positioning and z-indexing. There is a button on the panel that, when clicked, reveals the drawer by animating the top margin using jQuery. The reason I'm doing this with jQuery is to support IE8/9.

I've looked at the documentation for $animation regarding ng-show and ng-hide but I'm a bit confused as to how it actually works when defining the jQuery implementation.

```
<div class="drawer" ng-show="player.isDrawerOpen()"></div>

<div class="panel">
    <button ng-click="player.openDrawer()"></button>
</div>

angular.module('App')
.animation('.drawer', ['$log',
    function($log) {
        return {
            addClass: function(element, className, done) {
                $log.log(element, className, done);

                jQuery(element).animate({
                    marginTop: '0',
                    duration: 2000
                }, done);

                return function(isCancelled) {
                    if (isCancelled) {
                        jQuery(element).stop();
                    }
                };
            },
            removeClass: function(element, className, done) {
                $log.log(element, className, done);

                jQuery(element).animate({
                    marginTop: '-180px',
                    duration: 2000
                }, done);

                return function(isCancelled) {
                    if (isCancelled) {
                        jQuery(element).stop();
                    }
                };

            }
        };
    }]);
```

I can verify that when I click the button, the event I want to fire is broadcasted. I can also verify that player.isDrawerOpen() returns true after the button is clicked. But when ng-hide class is being removed from the .drawer div, nothing is getting logged by either addClass or removeClass.

I would like help figuring out how to tie the show/hide animation I've written up only to the drawer when ng-hide gets added or removed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. It wasn't my JS, rather I was still using angular.js v1.2.12 with angular-animate.js v1.2.14 and hadn't supplied the ngAnimate dependency. If the dependency is missing but you create a animation using angular.module().animation(), Angular doesn't throw a warning.